# PostGIS JOIN three tables

Tags: postgresql, join, postgis, spatial

I have three tables:

`Table_1` contains columns: `project_id` and `geom` (point).
`Table_2` contains columns: `polygon_name` and `geom` (multipolygon).
`Table_3` contains columns: `point_id` and `geom` (point).

First, I need to identify polygons from `Table_2` that intersect with points from `Table_1`. Once I have those polygons, I need to find points from `Table_3` that are inside those polygons.

The end result must include all points and their geom from `Table_3` that are inside the polygons that intersect with the geometries from `Table_1` and `Table_2` for desired `project_id`.

```
SELECT t3.point_id, t3.geom
FROM Table_3 AS t3
JOIN Table_2 AS t2 ON ST_Intersects(t3.geom, t2.geom)
JOIN Table_1 AS t1 ON ST_Intersects(t2.geom, t1.geom)
WHERE t1.project_id = desired_project_id;
```

I got the points from `Table_3`, but it seems that this query duplicates the results and the number of results is way too big.

---

I also tried this one, but it's not returning anything... just keep running and running

```
SELECT t3.point_id, t3.geom
FROM Table_3 AS t3
JOIN Table_2 AS t2 ON ST_Intersects(t3.geom, t2.geom)
JOIN Table_1 AS t1 ON ST_Within(t3.geom, ST_Intersection(t1.geom, t2.geom)
WHERE t1.project_id = desired_project_id;
```

Comment: If you only want distinct points of t3, then use DISTINCT.  That is what it is for.

Comment: Duplicate records can occure here, right? this is not a technical issue, but a problem with your functional description. If a point in t3 is part of multiple polygons in t2, and those polygons in t2 are part of the same project in t1, then you will get duplication